# Outlook API : Link to specific email in outlook.com via email ID

Tags: php, api, outlook

I'm using Outlook API to get a list of emails from my Inbox.

What I want to do next is to click on each email which will take me to the individual email page within Outlook.com

But I'm not sure if this is possible. Looking at the URLs within Outlook, it doesn't seem like there is any "message ID" in the URL.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you getting all email list outlook sending @odata.id. If you want to see full email by individual then make a call with (@odata.id)
Like below URL:
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/Users('78169f79-341a-4998-a411-4f29625b1638@5d043331-95cf-4453'
)/Messages('AAMkAGIxYmFjYzZiLWRjNWMtNDQ0MS05NzU4LTAyOWVhY2M0ODEz=')